# Why won't my array fill with '?'s?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

```
    public class MakeQuilt {

public static void main (String[] args){

  char [][] myBlock = new char [4][5];
  char [][] myQuilt = new char [12][4];

  for(int row = 0; row < myBlock.length; row++){
      for(int column = 0; column < myBlock[row].length; column++){
         if(column == 0 || row == 3)
            myBlock[row][column]='X';
         else if(row ==  column || (row == 2 && column == 1))
            myBlock[row][column]='+';
         else
            myBlock[row][column]='.';    
      }   
     }
    displayPattern(myBlock);
    displayPattern(myQuilt);
  }



  public static void displayPattern(char[][] myBlock){

   for(int row = 0; row < myBlock.length; row++){
      for(int column = 0; column < myBlock[row].length; column++){
         System.out.print(myBlock[row][column]);
          }
          System.out.println();
         }
         System.out.println();    
   }

    public static void fillQuilt(char[][] myQuilt){   
   for(int row = 0; row < myQuilt.length; row++){
      for(int column = 0; column < myQuilt[row].length; column++){
         myQuilt[row][column] =('?');
        }
  }
 }
}
```

Can't seem to figure out why my char array myQuilt won't fill with question marks but instead is filled with nothing? (output shows a bunch of 0's). Not sure how to change the displayPattern method to output ?'s in the myQuilt array.

Comment: It's not filled with question marks because you didn't fill it with question marks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before calling  `displayPattern`, you have to fill quilt somewhere. i.e.

```
displayPattern(myBlock);
fillQuilt(myQuilt);
displayPattern(myQuilt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Question: You define the `fillQuilt(...)` method where you would fill an array with question mark characters, but where do you ever call this method?

Answer: You don't (at least you don't show it), and if it's never called, it will never do its thing. The solution is to call the `fillQuilt` method, passing in myQuilt where you need it to do its actions: `fillQuilt(myQuilt);`. Understand that programming takes things very literally: they only do what you explicitly program them to do, nothing less, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any call to your `fillQuilt()` method in your `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to call fillQuilt() somewhere before printing?